# How to avoid Callback hell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback

How do I avoid callback hell in the following or similar cases,

```
[self saveSomethingToTheServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL saveSucceeded) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (saveSucceeded) {
                    [self showAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Save successful."];
                } else {
                    [self showAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Save failed."];
                }
            });
        }];
    });
}];
```

My understanding is that `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` and `showAlertControllerWithTitle:message:` must be executed on the main thread.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Just create a function i suppose?

Comment: @Lion To avoid having too many levels of nested callbacks.

Comment: @Tj3n Just one function would not suffice, I guess.

Comment: What you want to achieve? do you want to first dismiss VC and then want to show alert ?

Comment: @Lion In the above case, Yes. But it could be something more than just showing alert-controller. Making another network request or saving something to the local storage, for example.

Comment: and are you able to show alert ? after dismissing VC according to above code ?

Comment: Aamof, yes. Am I missing something here?

Comment: There's no other way than making function to make it less nested, not sure what else you need though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was fairly vague, so I'm taking a best guess at what you're asking. The only thing I can think of is that you're not happy with the nested calls. You can tidy that up with methods to an extent. e.g. you know that showing an alert always needs to be done on the main thread, so move the main thread code to your alert method:

```
[self saveSomethingToTheServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL saveSucceeded) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            NSString *message = saveSucceeded ? @"Save successful." : @"Save failed.";
            [self showAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:message];
        }];
    });
}];

- (void)showAlertControllerWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         //Show alert;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could consider removing the completion block from the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` call. i.e. does your alert being shown really depend on whether or not the view controller has dismissed?

```
[self saveSomethingToTheServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL saveSucceeded) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *message = saveSucceeded ? @"Save successful." : @"Save failed.";
        [self showAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:message];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

Ultimately though, sometimes you just have to nest callbacks. There's nothing really wrong with that.

**Edit:** I also replaced your if statement with a ternary one without really thinking about it. Not sure if you count that as "callback hell".

Comment: Maybe I should wrap around these methods containing completion blocks with a promises library like `Bolts` to flatten the code more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
[self saveSomethingToTheServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL saveSucceeded) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString *strMsg = saveSucceeded ? @"Save successful." : @"Save failed.";

        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

                }];

            });
        }];

        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Message" message:strMsg actions:@[okAction]];
    });

}];

- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString * _Nonnull)title message:(NSString * _Nonnull)msg actions:(NSArray * _Nonnull)actions {

    UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    for (UIAlertAction *action in actions) {
        [alertVC addAction:action];
    }

    [self presentViewController:alertVC animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

So on callback it will show alert with message and on ok button top alert will dismiss and also dismiss the presented view controller. So it will be on main thread.

Comment: Hey, thanks for making an effort :) But in your code, the nesting is still of the same level as the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wrap dismissViewControllerAnimated: with callback in main thread because it's already in main thread, also try to avoid duplicated code:

```
    [self saveSomethingToTheServerWithCompletion:^(BOOL saveSucceeded) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

            NSString *messageContent = saveSucceeded ? @"Save successful." : @"Save failed.";
            [self showAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:messageContent];
        }];
    });
}];
```

Comment: I could not find it anywhere in the Apple docs, on which thread the completion handler of `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` gets called. And `showAlertControllerWithTitle:message` must be executed on the main thread, so it is absolutely necessary to call it from the main thread.

Comment: Though what I *can* do is perform this wrapping inside `showAlertControllerWithTitle:message`.